Blazor WASM Environment is always Production
I have a .Net 8 Blazor Web App and the client's builder.HostEnvironment.Environment is always (locally and on Azure) set to 'Production' even if the Server builder.Environment is set to 'Development'
Why? I don't know about anywhere in the client project where I set it to 'Production'.

If the env is always set to 'Production',it may mean the app is being built using the Release configuration, which defaults to 'Production' environment. try using dotnet build --configuration Debug and
dotnet publish --configuration Debug

@mrSoh when I run in debug mode it's also set to 'Production'

check your web.config https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-the-client-side-environment-via-header

@Lee I don't have a web.config file in my project (only appsettings.json)

You could create a new project and test if the error is still present. If not it's somewhere in your code/config that we cannot see here.

Using 'DebugLocal' instead of 'Debug' solved it.

---EDIT---
This solution is not working for me anymore (I think since I've updated to dotnet 8.0.8).
It looks like the issue is that for some reason, the blazor-environment header is not being set from the server, doing it from code solved it for me.
Need to insert this code before app.UseStaticFiles();
var env = app.Environment.EnvironmentName;
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var url = context.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
    if (url.EndsWith("blazor.boot.json"))
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Append("blazor-environment", env);
    }

    return next(context);
});

For Request.GetEncodedUrl() to work, you need using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
See: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25152#issuecomment-2344329700
